# How to update macro when cell changes in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

So I'm new to VBA and I wanted to convert a bunch of employee hours to dollars by multiplying them by the hourly rate and vice versa. However I'm not sure how to handle a change in the hourly rate. So currently my code looks like this:

```
Sub dollarHour()

    Dim hrs As Range

    Set hrs = Range("D3:N33")

    For Each cell In hrs
        If cell.NumberFormat = "0.00" Then
            cell.Value = cell * Range("P37")
            cell.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

        Else
            cell.Value = cell / Range("P37")
            cell.NumberFormat = "0.00"

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

So basically my issue is the "P37" (the dollar multiplier) could be changed but it won't affect the cells until I run the macro again which changes up the original employee hours (which is something I don't want). So if I changed "P37" from $25 to $26 dollars for example, I want the cells in hrs to reflect that change. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Worksheet_Change` event.  This will run your macro every time $P$37 changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$P$37" Then
        dollarhour
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So I did that originally but I would prefer not to run the same macro again. That's because the hrs (the employee hours) range can end up changing if the user keeps changing the dollar multiplier. I'd like to somehow keep the original hrs Range static

Comment: Look into `Application.EnableEvents`